# Using Apexcharts appendData add datapoints to 3 series. How to add X Axis value?

Tags: javascript, charts, apexcharts

I'm using Apexcharts in a project. After I have created a graph with 3 lines (3 data series), I use appendData to add more datapoints to the 3 series in the chart. That works well.

But how do I add X Axis values?

Answer (score 0):

I saw a video which is solving your problem very well
Use the following link 
https://youtu.be/JDEe_HegXNg

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).